# Contradictory info about beets and hormone balance

Tags: nutrition, diet, testosterone, estrogen, gynecomastia-man-boobs

Searching online for "beets testosterone" there are sources that state that [beets boost testosterone levels](https://longevity.technology/lifestyle/add-these-juices-to-your-diet-today-to-boost-testosterone/).
e.g.

> The vitamin and antioxidant content of beetroot is high. It is also
> rich in dietary nitrates, which boost testosterone levels.

Searching online for "beets gynecomastia", there are sources that state that [beets increase estrogen levels](https://synergywellnesscenter.com/blog/is-your-diet-causing-gynecomastia/) (hence men should avoid beets):

> Beetroots: Beetroots contain high estrogen levels, which could cause your testosterone levels to decrease. Try to avoid this food to
> balance your hormones.

Also from an [article](https://www.gynecomastia-specialist.com/could-your-diet-cause-gynecomastia/) that states it is written by a doctor (but without references):

> The top foods that cause man breasts are soy products, beetroot, ....

If beets cause gynecomastia, that would mean that regardless of what they do to testosterone levels, they should increase estrogen abnormally high.

What is the source of this contradiction?
What do reputable medical sources report on this?

Comment: It's great that you cited articles but those are poor sources.  Blogs aren't reliable unless they link to a good study which was properly interpreted, something fairly rare on the internet. It's not at all unusual to find such contradictions. (That second source is a doozy! If it were true, most men in the US would have gynecomastia.)

Comment: @anongoodnurse: The second and third articles state that the authors are doctors. What would be the reason they write such articles without stating any reference to back up anything?

Comment: The second author sells "wellness" services. You land on the page from a search engine, read it, are scared, and then buy their service to get "well". The third author is a plastic surgeon. You land on the page trying to find information and then end up undergoing plastic surgery. They are both just thinly veiled advertisements.

Comment: @anongoodnurse "_If it were true, most men in the US would have gynecomastia._" -- And nearly all the men in Slavic countries where beets are a staple.

Comment: @IanCampbell - On the nail! That second source includes so many staples in US diets that it applies to nearly everyone, so all men need/will need his services. @ Smith: They want money. One of the first things I look for when I land on a website is to see if it is a "for profit" site. With a few exceptions, I pretty much just disregard those.

Comment: @IanCampbell: Oh, I see. So 1) would these kind of for-profit websites influence other blogs to share similar info? E.g in the same google search for "beets gyno" I see few others that don't appear for-profit 2) how come these doctors would include foods that anyone searching for the claims would see the contradiction? Is it laziness or is there some intention there?

Comment: @anongoodnurse: please have a look at my comment too

Comment: It's just people trying to make money and not caring if they're accurate or consistent. Stick to web sites operated by credible sources such as government agencies (CDC, NHS, etc), medical institutions (Mayo, Johns Hopkins, etc), medical journals (JAMA), and search engines that search only academic and research sites like google scholar.

Comment: @CareyGregory: Do these sites also influence other blogs etc to include this information?

Comment: I don't know, probably. But they don't influence reputable sites. Nobody in the science community even looks at those sites, much less gets influenced by them.